# Call UITextField Editing Did Begin only once

Tags: swift, uitextfield

When the user click on the textField i send them to another screen (using Editing did begin) so he can select the option he wants (i use the textfield for design purpose so i cant change this for a button or pickerView or etc)

The question is, when he selects the option he wants i pop this view and send the value back to the textField screen (using delegate).

Now i tried to do `textField.resignFirstResponder()` but this does not work, since the textField is still selected the action goes into a loop. I can use `textField.isDisable` but the user can't change the value anymore.

I can fix this by simple putting

```
if(textField.text != "")
{
 return
}
```

In the textField action. But this is far away from a solution, its more like band-aid on a leak.

And with this if the user select the textField again since i have the if above in the code he will not go to the select screen unless he delete the entire text.

How can i solve this? Since `resignFirstResponder` its not working. Maybe im doing it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use `view.endEditing(true)` instead?

Comment: Are you able to provide the project code (or a sample project) so that we can see the full app in action and provide you with a solution?

Comment: @Gusfat, check your textfield delegate control

Comment: Man i cant believe i forgot something so simple as that... i always forget to set the delegate. Sorry guys! @ManikandanD if you want to reply that as an answer i'll give you the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Gusfat, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set Delegate for your textfield

```
textFieldName.delegate = self
```